# Does the New Tax Bill Affect 2017 Taxes For Flow Through Entities / S Corp?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, tax-deduction, s-corporation

Will the new tax bill affect flow through entities' / S Corps' 2017 tax rates?  Specifically, will you be able to take advantage of the new 20% deduction for 2017?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the new tax bill doesn't kick in until 2018

Comment: @JohnFx: a few parts of it affects 2017 or previous years

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Section 11011 of [H.R. 1](https://www.congress.gov/115/bills/hr1/BILLS-115hr1enr.pdf) (pages 10-18) lays out the 20 percent deduction for pass through entities. Subsection (e) reads:

> (e) EFFECTIVE DATE.—The amendments made by this section shall apply to taxable years beginning after December 31, 2017.

That is, the 20% deduction does not apply to the return you are filing for 2017.

Your first question, "how will the new tax bill affect tax rates," is far too general and situation-specific to answer in any useful way, unfortunately.